# How can I fix this to add images from HTML div element to google map marker popup content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

This is downloaded complete Javascript for google maps api that I'm customizing for my needs. What this code does is creating markers with popup info. The text in the content of the popus is from CSS file, with the following information: name, address1, address2 and postalCode. I need to add different images underneath the text info for each marker, I have added variable for image and assume it should add something like something like this `"<img src=''>"` in the var `iwContent` variable but i can not figure out how to

```
var map;
var infoWindow;
var markersData = [{
    lat: 41.998079,
    lng: 21.426156,
    name: "Camping Praia da Barra",
    address1: "Rua Diogo Cão, 125",
    address2: "Praia da Barra",
    postalCode: "3830-772 Gafanha da Nazaré"
}];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.601203, -8.668173),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.close();
    });
    displayMarkers();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function displayMarkers() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat, markersData[i].lng);
        var name = markersData[i].name;
        var address1 = markersData[i].address1;
        var address2 = markersData[i].address2;
        var postalCode = markersData[i].postalCode;
        var image = markersData[i].image;
        createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode, image);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode, image) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        title: name,
        icon: 'anchor_point_with shadow.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' + '<div class="iw_title">' + name + '</div>' + '<div class="iw_content">' + address1 + '<br />' + address2 + '<br />' + postalCode + '</div></div>'; //i guess change should be made at this line
        infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<img src="...` to the string `ìwContent` including `image`, after defining it in `markersData`

```js
var markersData = [{
  lat: 41.998079,
  lng: 21.426156,
  name: "Camping Praia da Barra",
  address1: "Rua Diogo Cão, 125",
  address2: "Praia da Barra",
  postalCode: "3830-772 Gafanha da Nazaré",
  image: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"
}];


function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.601203, -8.668173),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });


  displayMarkers();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



function displayMarkers() {


  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


  for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat, markersData[i].lng);
    var name = markersData[i].name;
    var address1 = markersData[i].address1;
    var address2 = markersData[i].address2;
    var postalCode = markersData[i].postalCode;
    var image = markersData[i].image;

    createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode, image);


    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}


function createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode, image) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title: name,
    //icon: 'anchor_point_with shadow.png'
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
      '<div class="iw_title">' + name + '</div>' +
      '<div class="iw_content">' + address1 + '<br />' +
      address2 + '<br />' +
      postalCode + '</div>'+
      '<img src="'+image+'"></div>'; //i guess change should be made at this line


    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);


    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
};

initialize();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var markersData = [{
  lat: 41.998079,
  lng: 21.426156,
  name: "Camping Praia da Barra",
  address1: "Rua Diogo Cão, 125",
  address2: "Praia da Barra",
  postalCode: "3830-772 Gafanha da Nazaré",
  image: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"
}];


function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.601203, -8.668173),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });


  displayMarkers();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



function displayMarkers() {


  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


  for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat, markersData[i].lng);
    var name = markersData[i].name;
    var address1 = markersData[i].address1;
    var address2 = markersData[i].address2;
    var postalCode = markersData[i].postalCode;
    var image = markersData[i].image;

    createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode, image);


    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}


function createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode, image) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title: name,
    //icon: 'anchor_point_with shadow.png'
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
      '<div class="iw_title">' + name + '</div>' +
      '<div class="iw_content">' + address1 + '<br />' +
      address2 + '<br />' +
      postalCode + '</div>'+
      '<img src="'+image+'"></div>'; //i guess change should be made at this line


    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);


    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
};

initialize();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```